# Woocommerce - Reposition Title on Archive Page

Tags: php, woocommerce, title, archive

I am using woocommerce and would like to move the title on my archive page to above the thumbnail. Right now it is below the thumbnail.

Is there a way to unhook the title in its current position and move it? Thanks!

Here is a [link](http://www.happyhealthymarket.com) to my website.

Comment: sure there is, we need a link or code to help you

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Just added a link!

Comment: got cha, so I see the page. I see the page title, I'm having trouble figuring out which thumnail you are referring to

Comment: One more thing I wanted to point out. Not all themes are created equal. Not all modifications are necessarily done the same way in Wordpress either. You may have to get to this fix by altering the page.php, a woocomerce page.php, or if lucky, the markup in a page you created for this. Ideally, this is better done with access to the wordpress back end and root directory. But I'll try to help with just the inspector to look at

Comment: All of the product titles below the thumbnails. I would simply like to reposition so that these titles appear above their thumbnail. Hopefully that makes sense??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to locate the shop page. In your directory follow your directory to this location

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php

And find this code:

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>   

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <?php
          do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    <?php
          do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

</a>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

 </li>
```

replace it with :

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <?php
          do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

    <?php
          do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

</a>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

 </li>
```

Lastly, work the css to line it up the way you want it. Like I said, not every template is created equal. This is a general fix for this issue. But it shouldn't be too far from the actual fix. You may consider checking the space you have above the image and again, allow css to modify this part

Comment: Perfect thank you! Now the title isn't a hyper-link nor does it have a rollover effect. Do you know how to correct this?

Comment: do you see the <a href....> tag in the code above? add that to the front of the h3 title tag and close it with </a>

Comment: I see it worked! Happy for ya. Btw, I love the stuff you sell! I may hold on to this link lol

Comment: Got it to work. YOU ROCK! Thank you soo much, glad you like the site :) Still a work in progress. I have a couple more simple questions like the last one but don't want to spam up this thread. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Make a new question and @LOTUSMS me. I should be able to get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think the best way to do this is:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 5 );
```